# how to display the edittext in the listview in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

whenever I enter text in the english language in edit text then it will appear in the another language .how to change it to the english language

Comment: Make your question more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what this question mean... please try again

Comment: what is the need for adding edittext in listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use scrollview in order to add multiple edittexts and so it can be scrollable.